# How to stop Gnome Keyring from asking for Login password, like it used to?

Tags: cinnamon, pam, lightdm, gnome-keyring

Previously, Gnome Keyring only asked for the Default Keyring password when I attempted to launch Chrome. I tried playing around with settings in Seahorse to see if there was a work around for this, other than leaving the password database unencrypted. During that process I switched the default keyring to the Login Keyring. Obviously, that did not impact Chrome asking for a keyring password; so, I switched the default keyring back to the Default Keyring.

Now, when Lightdm auto logs me in to Cinnamon, Gnome Keyring asks for the Login password every time, after logging in. I cancel that prompt and Gnome Keyring asks for the Default Keyring when I launch Chrome. (I'm fine with this) How do i return to the old behaviour of having the Login Keyring encrypted, but never asking for my user password? (default uses root)

I never explicitly set up a password for the Login Keyring prior, and I'm pretty sure it was encrypted before since there has been a Login keyring file since I installed Gnome Keyring a few weeks back.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get the annoying prompts when starting the Chrome browser.
Internet-research suggested the following resolution which I successfully adopted.

1. Create a duplicate of the menu item, preserving the original, just in case.
2. On the duplicate, the command was
   /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
3. On the duplicate, I changed the command to 
   /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic

Answer (score 0):

Tried multiple ways to solve this issue - this is the method that worked for me, finally disabling the prompt permanently - Linux Mint V 19.1

Find google-chrome-stable launcher in  /usr/share/applications - open the launcher with sudo gedit or geany, etc - scroll down to:
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U 
and change to
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic %U
Save